# Выводится только первый элемент из списка, Modx Revo

Tags: php, modx

Не получается вывести все значения из множественного списка в TV поле [[*related_authors]];

Что прописал в параметрах TV поля:
1) Тип ввода: Список(множественный выбор)
2) Возможные значения: @EVAL return $modx->runSnippet('RelatedAuthorList',array('parent' => 44));

Код сниппета:

```js
    <?php
$parent = $modx->getOption('parent',$scriptProperties,44);
$parentObj = $modx->getObject('modResource',$parent);
if (!($parentObj instanceof modResource)) { return ''; }
$criteria = $modx->newQuery('modResource'); 
$criteria->where(['deleted' => 0, 'published' => 1]); 
$criteria->sortby('menuindex','ASC');
$resArray = $parentObj->getMany('Children', $criteria);
$resources = [];
foreach($resArray as $res) {
  if ($res instanceof modResource) {
    $resources[] = $res->get('pagetitle') . '==' . $res->get('id');
  }
}
$out = implode("||",$resources);

return $out;
```

3) Тип вывода: разделитель(запятая)

На странице непосредственно вывожу вот так:
[[If? &subject=`[[*related_authors]]` &operator=`!empty` &then=`[[$author_block_min]]` &else=``]]

Чанк $author_block_min:

[[RenderRelatedObjects? &input=`[[*related_authors]]` &tpl=`<a href="[[~[[+id]]]]" class="auto-margin">[[+pagetitle]]</a>`]]

Код сниппета RenderRelatedObjects:

```js
<?php
if (empty($input)) { return 'This article is so unique, that we couldn\'t find anything related to it!'; }
$tpl = $modx->getOption('tpl',$scriptProperties,'relatedPagesTpl');
if ($modx->getChunk($tpl) == '') { return 'We found some related pages, but don\'t know how to present it.'; }
$ids = explode(',', $input);
$output = array();
foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
  $resource = $modx->getObject('modResource',array(
    'published' => 1,
    'id' => $value));
  if ($resource instanceof modResource) {
    $ta = $resource->toArray();
    $tvs = $resource->getTemplateVars();
    foreach ($tvs as $tv) {
       $ta[$tv->get('name')] = $tv->get('value');
    }
    $ta['_url'] = $modx->makeUrl($resource->id, null, null, 'full');
    $output[] = $modx->getChunk($tpl,$ta);
  }
}
return implode('',$output);
```

Но на странице отображается только первый выбранный элемент. В чем может быть проблема?